# web2py - translate long texts

Tags: translation, web2py

I (think I) understand how to translate strings in web2py.
My question is: what is the preferred way to translate large texts.
For example "History of our company..."
Including them in a dictionary seems weird to me...
Maybe creating different html snippets for different languages and including them in the view depending on a session variable?

And another one: when the site grows big and the number of words and sentences is huge, is this dictionary-based translation efficient?

Thanks,
Gergely

Answer (score 0):

I guess your question is about internationalization support in web2py. [I had a similar question a while ago.](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/web2py/M37dUVosJkE)

To start with you may look at [flatpages plugin](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/web2py/sgbPpPZ4QX8)

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to take a look at it. However it's not exactly what I want. I don't want to store the text in db. At the same time I don't want different view files for every language. I think I will stay with T for labels and short texts and include prefixed html snippets for long texts.I would like to avoid duplicating logic as much as possible. (even logic in the views)

Comment: If you don't want to store the text in db it is not worth looking.